# Consulta al Programar JAVA en VS Code

Tags: java, vscode, ide

Mi consulta esta relacionada al Editor VS Code ya que al ejecutar el código en NetBeans no me da error.

Al usar el VS Code si uso el Scanner pero con `.useDelimeter("\n);` me arroja un error.
Al usar la variable para leer el `Scanner.nextLine();` me arroja error.
Si uso el Scanner sin el `useDelimeter` y al leer el Scanner solo uso `next()` no tengo error, sin embargo, el código lo necesito ya sea con el `useDelimeter` o el `nextLine`, no se si es problema de configuración del editor o algún plugin, pero en el IDE me funciona sin problemas.

Código sin error:

```java
public void crearProducto() throws Exception {
    try {
      Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
      Producto p = new Producto();

      System.out.println("Ingrese el código del producto.");
      int codigo = read.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto.");
      String nombre = read.next();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el precio del prodcuto.");
      double precio = read.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el código del fabricante.");
      int codigoF = read.nextInt();

      p.setCodigo(codigo);
      p.setNombre(nombre);
      p.setPrecio(precio);
      p.setCodigoFabricante(codigoF);
      dao.guardarProducto(p);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    }

  }
```

Código con error:

```java
public void crearProducto() throws Exception {
    try {
      Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
      Producto p = new Producto();

      System.out.println("Ingrese el código del producto.");
      int codigo = read.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto.");
      String nombre = read.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el precio del prodcuto.");
      double precio = read.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el código del fabricante.");
      int codigoF = read.nextInt();

      p.setCodigo(codigo);
      p.setNombre(nombre);
      p.setPrecio(precio);
      p.setCodigoFabricante(codigoF);
      dao.guardarProducto(p);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    }

  }
```

Este es el error que me arroja al ejecutar el segundo código:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException      
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)   
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
            at tienda.servicios.ProductoService.crearProducto(ProductoService.java:22)
            at tienda.servicios.Interfase.menu(Interfase.java:38)
            at tienda.main.main(main.java:8)
```

Si le quito el `.useDelimeter` y que quedo sólo con el `nextLine()`, al llegar a esa línea se la salta y al revisar el nombre queda en blanco.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que debes de escapar la diagonal inversa en tu String, de lo contrario te arrojará error.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
```

Si quieres revisa la [documentación oficial de Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html). Ahí verás un ejemplo de cómo se usa el useDelimiter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por parte de la excepción es porque no encuentra la secuencia de caracteres que cumpla tu delimitador, por eso el [inputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, hice el cambio que me comenta pero sigue con error, el problema solo me lo da en el editor VS Code, en el NetBeans no tengo problema, es solo que quiero usar el VS Code para hacer todo el código.